# Ranking of genotype plot based on temperature of canopy

Tags: r, plot, ranking, temperature

I am working on crop water stress monitoring. I have thermal images of different crop genotypes of same day. I would like to plot temperature values for genotypes as black and white horizontally spaced diagram as shown in image that shows black colour as higher temperature and white colour as low temperatures. Pleas help me. The link of the demo data for 20 genotypes is given below-

[Demo Temperature data for 20 genotypes](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0wkgtgoif86rd9/Genotypewise-TempearturedataDemo.xlsx?dl=0) (First column is Genotype No., second column is min temp and third column is max temp.)

A similar figure from different study is attached herewith.

[image: Rank of genotypes based on temperature values]

Comment: You'll get a better response if you include some [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @neilfws thanks, I am adding example data.

Comment: Sounds like you have an exciting project on your hands, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @W.Dodge , I have done CWSI (crop water stress Index) Computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of plots can be simply  created using  MS excel.

Select the data arranged in 2D matrix, Insert (on the main Excel bar), Chart, Surface, contour. If it defaults to the wrong sort of surface chart, click on Change chart type, surface, contour.

This info was provided by 
Dr. Hamlyn G Jones,
Emeritus Professor of Plant Ecology,
Division of Plant Sciences, University of Dundee.